# Unable to create linked service pointing to my local machine path using self hosted integration runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service

I am unable to create a linked service (file system) i.e a path pointing to my local machine using self-hosted integration runtime.

I have installed azure self-hosted integration runtime in my local machine. I have created a shared folder in order to create a linked service.

However, it is throwing me error as below : -

[image]

Can you please let me know why I am receiving this error while trying to establish a connection.

I assume this is related to local machine IP address that is not within the range of VNET. Is it related to gateway subnet. I am not familiar with azure virtual networking concepts.

My simple purpose is creating a linked service with source from my own local machine, run copy activity to copy it to an azure blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The value of the property is invalid: Access to <***> is denied, resolved IP address is <****>, network type is OnPremise. Access to anishalaptop is denied, resolved IP address is <***>, network type is OnPremise.
```

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#sample-linked-service-and-dataset-definitions),

> Enable the access to the local machine under Self-hosted integration runtime. By default, it's disabled.

That may be the reason for getting the above error. Run PowerShell as administrator and disable security validation to enable access to the file system of the local machine using the command below:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\5.0\Shared\"
 .\dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation
```

[image]

The linked service will be created and tested successfully, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: What is the work of dmgcmd.exe script.? Does it have any impact on the firewall of the system. Any adverse impact?